# Archival of CMS item

Tags: 2013, archival

Is it possible in SDL Tridion to archive items like Components.

I know SDL Tridion maintains a version history of each Component but in case there are too many versions we purge the data using purge utility which will delete the previous version(s) based on criteria provided.

Is it possible to archive those?

Answer (score 4):

SDL Tridion is a CMS and not build to be a data warehouse, hence the options to purge old versions which is considered standard maintenance.

There are numerous options for you to archive old data, but let me list a few simple ones;

1. Make a full backup of your CMS database before you purge

   *This could be your archive mechanism, if you even need to see the old items back, you could setup a second CMS to which to connect the archived database. Then you have the option to "view back in time" on a separate system and use Content Porter for instance to restore some of those old items to your current server.*
2. Use SDL Tridion Archive Manager

   *This doesn't archive the items on the CMS, but actually archives your published items. It is useful for auditing purposes regarding your website and gives a means of looking back in time on your website. There is no way to restore old content, it is just an archive of the published items/website.*
3. Build something custom suiting your needs based on the available APIs

   *Particularly thinking of the new 2013 SP1 Import Export API, as described by [Eric Huiza](http://erichuiza.blogspot.nl/2013/12/tridion-2013-sp1-import-export-api.html) and [Anton Minko](http://tridioninternals.blogspot.nl/).*

Answer (score 2):

If you purge the data, that information will be permanently deleted from the CMS Database.
In case you want to keep those versions, the best option is to perform a back up of the database.

In case you want to retrieve the versions deleted you could restore the DB in other environment and access those versions.